# Waiting for get request response from JS does not work

Tags: javascript, get, request

In my javascript code I have:

```
function getThing(){
    var url = "myhost/thing";
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET", url, false);
    x.onload = function (){
        return x.responseText
    }
    x.send(null);
}

console.log(getThing())
```

And `console log` gives me `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not returning anything from `getThing()` function.

AJAX is asynchronous, so when you are calling getThing() you are not going to wait for the ajax to return value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: And how do I make the call synchronous?

Comment: It's not async.  Delete the `x.onload` block and return `x.responseText` after `x.send`

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTP request is executed asynchronously, and `getThing` is not returning anything other than `undefined`. Instead, your `onload` handler is returning the requested value, which is not used.

Instead, you need to wait with logging until the call has returned:

```
function getThing(){
    var url = "myhost/thing";
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET", url);
    x.onload = function (){
        console.log(x.responseText);
    }
    x.send(null);
}

getThing();
```

Comment: And if I need the result OUTSIDE the getThing function? some while loop maybe?

Comment: That's not trivial. Try looking into [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Are you sure it's async?

Comment: @James Yeah, never mind -- missed the sync. parameter.

Comment: @YawningMilk You should not use synchronous requests on the main thread, that feature is deprecated and is slowly getting killed. [Read more.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)